# Typescript: Looping through files and folders in a SFTP connection

Tags: node.js, typescript, sftp

Using node v16.18.0, Typescript v10.9.1 and ssh2-sftp-client I have established a connection to a SFTP server.

I have to loop through all the files and copy them to another location (AWS S3).  To do this I have to get a list of the files inside of a SFTP location (root or folder).  This is an example of a SFTP folder’s contents:

- TestFolder1
- TestFolder2
- Afile.txt
- Bfile.txt
- Zfile.txt

And this is my code to get a list of the files

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();

await sftp.connect({
    host: params.SourceAddress,
    port: params.SourcePort,
    username: params.SourceUserId,
    password: params.SourcePassword,
    privateKey: params.SourceSftpKey,
});

//The exception occurs on this next line
const files = await sftp.list(`/${params.SourcePath}`);
```

and this is the error I get:

> Error: list: No such file /##.##.##.##/TestFolder1

If I remove all folders and have only files in this location then everything runs as expected.

1. How can I get a list of files from this location without getting the exception for folders?
2. Later I will need to get a list of the folders and not the files.  How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:
https://openbase.com/js/node-sftp-client/documentation

Although this look similar to my code, this one will return folders and files:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();
sftp.connect({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '8080',
    username: 'username',
    password: '******'
}).then(() => {
    return sftp.list('/pathname');
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data, 'the data info');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, 'catch error');
});
```

Hope this helps.